# How do I let python know that I click "search" button for aspx website?

Tags: python, asp.net, web-scraping

I want to get all the shareholding in CCASS and % of the total number of issued shares from on 03/04/2017. Here is the link.

http://www.hkexnews.hk/sdw/search/mutualmarket.aspx?t=hk

Here is my code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://www.hkexnews.hk/sdw/search/mutualmarket.aspx?t=hk"
data = {
"sortBy":"",
"alertMsg":"",
"ddlShareholdingDay":"03",
"ddlShareholdingMonth":"04",
"ddlShareholdingYear":"2017",
}
req = requests.post(url, data)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

Then the output shows the data of the original website, which is the data without clicking "search" button.

I think the problem is form data, I don't know how to let python know that I click "search" button.

Here is the form data.
[form data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3V9G.png)

The rest of the form data are __VIEWSTATE, __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR and __EVENTVALIDATION.

By the way, I don't know what is btnSearch.x and btnSearch.y, they are always changing when I click "search".

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = "http://www.hkexnews.hk/sdw/search/mutualmarket.aspx?t=hk"
r=requests.get(html)
c=r.content
soup=BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")


all_tables=[[td.text for td in tr.find_all('td')] for tr in soup.find_all('table')[2].find_all('tr')]
stock_info=[[sub_item.replace('\r\n', '') for sub_item in item] for item in all_tables]
for stock in stock_info[2:]:
    print("Stock code {}".format(stock[0]))
    print("Stock Name {}".format(stock[1]))
    print("Shareholding in CCASS {}".format(stock[2]))
    print("Shares Percentage {}".format(stock[3]))
    print("---------------------------------- \n")
```

Sample of output:

```
Stock code                                     1                            
Stock Name                                 CK HUTCHISON HOLDINGS LIMITED                            
Shareholding in CCASS                                 11,746,298                            
Shares Percentage                                 0.30%                            
---------------------------------- 

Stock code                                     2                            
Stock Name                                 CLP HOLDINGS LIMITED                            
Shareholding in CCASS                                 3,160,800                            
Shares Percentage                                 0.11%                            
---------------------------------- 

Stock code                                     3                            
Stock Name                                 HONG KONG AND CHINA GAS COMPANY LIMITED, THE                            
Shareholding in CCASS                                 17,183,763                            
Shares Percentage                                 0.11%                            
---------------------------------- 

Stock code                                     4                            
Stock Name                                 WHARF (HOLDINGS) LIMITED, THE                            
Shareholding in CCASS                                 2,828,000                            
Shares Percentage                                 0.09%                            
----------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: However, my problem is that the aspx. url doesn't change, so I don't know how to scrape data for a special date

Comment: For the special date you will need selenium automation. If current solution worked for you , you can  [Accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow)

Comment: Thank you very much, but I edit my question just now, could you please take a look?

Comment: Thanks, selenium worked for me, so I accepted your answer for both selenium and beautiful soup!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code to handle date, 360 days max. to scrap, include the date of typhoon no. 8 pausing trading

```
for i in range(360):
    datetime_today = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=i)
    datetime_today = datetime_today + datetime.timedelta(days=-1)
    trade_day = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(datetime_today), '%Y-%m-%d').date()

    weekdaylist = [0,1,2,3,4]
    if trade_day.weekday() in weekdaylist:
        day_list.append(str(trade_day))
holidays = ['2017-08-23', '2017-10-02', '2017-10-05', '2017-05-30', '2017-05-01', '2017-05-03', '2017-04-17', '2017-04-14', '2017-04-04','2017-01-30','2017-01-31','2017-01-02']
day_list = [x for x in day_list if x not in holidays]
```